# Indexing in mutliple joins in sql

Tags: sql, performance, join, indexing

I need to develop a search engine. All data is saved in the Oracle database which contains approx 300GB of data. I need to join multiple tables to gather all the info I need and search from there. It went **super** slow without indexing(always time out) when I joined 4 tables together. Here is an example of my query:

```
select distinct t1.a, t1.b, t2.c , t1.d, t3.e, t5.f, t1.g, t4.k 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.a = t1.a
inner join table3 t3 on t3.l = t2.l
left outer join table4 t4 on t4.d = t1.d
inner join table5 t5 on t5.a = t1.a
where t1.a > 0 and t1.b < 2 and t2.c > 3 and t1.d > 4 
and t3.e > 5 and t5.f > 6;
```

I know there is a thing called ***index*** that could speed up the runtime. The question is how could I make the index?

Should I make indexes for each join key in each table?

Also for the where statement, how could I make a cross table index? For example, column a and column c is from different tables, how could I make an index to have them both?

Comment: Please edit your question to delete the "additional question". It's 1 actual question per posted question on this site.

Comment: The query is malformed. The predicate `t5.f > 6` silently converts the outer join into an inner join. Please fix the query before we can help with the optimization.

Comment: What's the specific database? Available optimizations options vary depending on the engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want indexes on all columns used for join conditions in the table being joined to, but you should add the range condition after the key (where used):

```
create index table2_ac on table2(a, c);
create index table3_le on table3(l, e);
create index table4_d on table4(d);
create index table5_af on table5(a, f);
```

You can't make "cross table" indexes.

Creating an index over the columns used in the `where` clause may help:

```
create index table1_abd on table1(a, b, d);
```

Finally, move conditions on joined tables from the `where` clause into the join condition:

```
select distinct t1.a, t1.b, t2.c , t1.d, t3.e, t5.f, t1.g, t4.k 
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.a = t1.a and t2.c > 3
inner join table3 t3 on t3.l = t2.l and t3.e > 5
left outer join table4 t4 on t4.d = t1.d
left outer join table5 t5 on t5.a = t1.a and t5.f > 6
where t1.a > 0 and t1.b < 2 and t1.d > 4
```

Which also fixes the subtle problem with your query that by putting conditions on left joined tables in the *where* clause changes that join type from *outer* to *inner*.

Comment: The columns of the last index do not belong to that table. Also multi-table indexes are available under limited circumstances in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: @the thx. Skimmed that. Answer adjusted.